# Why does the first operation on a Pandas DataFrame take the longest time?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I've been doing some profiling of some Pandas DataFrame operations and have noticed that the first operation takes a significantly longer time, there's some kind of static overhead involved.

For example in a notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randn(1000), 'b': np.random.randn(1000)})
```

---

```
%%time
df['sum'] = df['a'] + df['b']
```

Wall time: 14 ms

---

```
%%time
df['sum2'] = df['a'] + df['b']
```

Wall time: 1 ms

---

I did %prun and saw that the first operation is making calls to nt.stat, winreg.OpenKey, like it's doing some filesystem operations for some reason. I've noticed similar behaviour on a Linux machine too.

What is the cause and is it possible to fix it? It's really slowing down some processing I'm doing involving performing a batch of operations on a collection of small DataFrames and having this first-operation overhead that takes longer than all the rest combined...
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Using Python 3.5.3 and Pandas 0.25.3

Comment: Can't reproduce, it's taking the same for me

Comment: Did you try with a fresh Python kernel? Which version of Python/Pandas?

Comment: I can reproduce this behavior with Python 3.8 and `pandas==1.0.2`. Running `%prun df['a'] + df['b']` two times gives 1293 function calls for the first one and 373 for the second. It looks like Pandas is doing some lazy imports here. Running the two operations on two different data frames yields the same gain. So this should be due to a one-time operation causing some overhead (e.g. imports). When you say you're operating on a batch of data frames, you should see the decreased performance only for the first data frame, not for each data frame.

Comment: It actually was happening multiple times (one for each DF) however I've now found what the issue is.
It's because I was getting my list of DataFrames from iterating over a groupby() result which returned DataFrame slices, then assigning new columns to the slices, which resulted in warning:
SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
This wasn't showing up because the process was being run by a web server. Each time this warning comes it causes a delay
I fixed the problem by creating a copy of the input DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

The issue was happening multiple times in a single session (not just once-off for imports) but I've found out why.
It's because I was getting my list of DataFrames from iterating over a groupby() result which returned DataFrame slices, then assigning new columns to the slices, which resulted in warning:

> SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame.

This wasn't showing up because the process was being run by a web server. Each time this warning comes it causes the delay I was noticing.

Ifixed the problem by creating a copy of the input DataFrame before applying operations